# adding transition on scrollto feature in website when user clicks an anchor tag/link

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm trying to figure out how I can add transition on my website when user clicks on an anchor tag/link going to the specific div or part of the website. Sorry for my bad english.
I added the javascript on my website but it still scrolls instantly on to the specific div with no transition

Here is my work in progress.

**HTML**

```
<!--NAVIGATION -->
<div class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>


<!--CONTENT -->
<div class="content">
    <div id="home" class="munla-slides home-slide"></div>
    <div id="menu" class="munla-slides menu-slide"></div>
    <div id="gallery" class="munla-slides gallery-slide"></div>
    <div id="contact" class="munla-slides contact-slide"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}

html, body{height:100%; overflow:hidden}

.sidebar{
    width:20%; 
    float:left; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:beige
}

.content{
    width:80%; 
    float:left; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:teal; 
    overflow:hidden
}

.munla-slides{height:100%; width:100%; overflow-x:hidden}
.munla-slides .box1{height:500px; width:300px; background-color:grey}

.home-slide{background-color:#774040}
.menu-slide{background-color:#17D8C5}
.gallery-slide{background-color:#F96327}
.contact-slide{background-color:#D34593}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Jus for a clarification.. have you added jquery.js file to your page?? if not pls visit http://jquery.com/ and add latest version of jquery file to you page and try again...

Comment: yes I did and it does not include or add any transition when I click on the anchor tag

Comment: Jus press F12 in the browser and see if there is any error in the console.

Comment: I did that also and there weren't any errors appearing.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle??

Comment: Here is the fiddle. It seem to be behaving badly http://jsfiddle.net/or5o94a5/

Comment: I even tried an alternative in adding jquery  https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Ok.. will look into this.. give me some moment